# libcurl continue running after writefunction callback

Tags: c, libcurl, pushbullet

I am trying to use the libcurl library in C with the pushbullet api. I am trying to connect to a stream at https://stream.pushbullet.com/streaming/. The problem is once the callback function is called when it receives any data, the connection is closed. I would like to keep it running indefinitely and have it call the callback function be called every time it receives new data.

Here is the code I tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int getwss_cb(char *data) {
    printf("Received data: %s\n", data);
}

int getwss(void) {
    CURL *easyhandle = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://stream.pushbullet.com/streaming/<access-token>");
    curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, getwss_cb);
    curl_easy_perform(easyhandle);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically I need the getwss() function to continue running even after running getwss_cb()

Comment: What do you mean by indefinitely? What is your end goal?

Comment: I need it to continue running so that the getwss_cb is called everytime there is something new in the stream. The url I used will send new data as a form of notification and I need a function to run everytime there is such a notification

Comment: Are you sure that this API endpoint is a proper socket? I don't know this API, but it seems like this endpoint is just for generating an access token to be handed off to another socket.

Comment: No I use my personal access token in the code to reach the endpoint. The actual data that is returned is a small JSON string like `{"Type": "nop"}`

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst I have edited the question to make it more clear, hopefully you can understand my question now

Comment: Can you refer us to the documentation for this endpoint? I tried doing a search myself but couldn't find anything on this specifically.

Comment: The docs talk about a web socket (was) at https://docs.pushbullet.com/#realtime-event-stream. The following answer gives the endpoint that I use https://stackoverflow.com/a/30387648. In any case I don't think there's a problem with the api. If I don't have a callback function I can see the notifications come correctly. I need to use a conditional based on the message so I need the callback function which is causing the problem the problem of ending the program as soon as it's run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback doesn't use the correct prototype and it doesn't return the correct return code:

```
size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);
```

See the full docs explaining the callback and what it should return in the documentation for the [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) option.

Also note that the data that is passed to the callback is *not* zero terminated so you can't just printf-%s it.

Comment: The printf still works properly. The message is printed on screen when run. Also I don’t really need the size and other stuff from the prototype which is why I didn’t include it. Do I still need to have it? I’ll try using size_t instead of int and let you know the result when I can

Comment: The printf may still work *accidentally*, sure - but relying on accidental behavior is not a good idea. You **should** use the correct and exact prototype as documented as otherwise you won't be able to get the full size of the incoming data.

Comment: I just made the changes you suggested but the results are the same.

Comment: `size_t getwss_cb(char *data, size_t size1, size_t nmemb1, void *userdata1) {
 printf("Data Recieved!\n");
}`

Comment: Sorry my bad. I tried running with `return 0;` but that doesnt make any difference either. I am not entirely sure if thats the correct line that should be used though.

Comment: As documented, returning 0 is certainly not the right way for a continued download.

Comment: ‘return 1;’ doesn’t work either. What would you suggest I use for the return code?

Comment: I recommend doing as the documentation says: *Your callback should return the number of bytes actually taken care of.*